# why is my code returning searchBar entry widget is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to write an application in python tkinter.
the code I wrote is returning that the searchBar variable is not defined.

code:

```
from Scripts import acquire, widgets
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox


def run():
    print("starting main")
    window = Tk()
    window.title("PyData Library Database Manager")
    window.geometry("1080x760")
    searchFrame = Frame(window)
    searchBar = Entry(searchFrame).grid(row=0, column=0)

    def search():
        global searchBar
        searchBarStr = searchBar.get()
        acquire.search(searchBarStr)

    searchGo = Button(searchFrame, text="Go", command=search).grid(row=0, column=1)
    searchFrame.grid(row=0, column=0)
    window.mainloop()
```

and some more code:

```
# acquire.py of PyData
# used to get data and search Data folder


def search(searchStr):
    print("searching for: %s" % searchStr)
```

I am trying to write a database application. the search function is supposed get the search data from the acquire search function, which is supposed to look at a Data directory structure, which contains folders Data and Images. In Data, we have text files for the entry data. I can't search for the right file if I can't get the search results: when I click "go", it returns an `searchBar is not defined` error.
Any ideas?

Comment: In `search()`, you have declared that `searchBar` is a global variable - but there is no global definition of that name; it was a local variable of `run()`.  Since `search()` is nested inside `run()`, it could have found the variable if you didn't have that `global` statement - an alternative would be to declare it as `global` in `run()`, as well (but then there's no point to nesting `search()` inside that function).

Comment: then it returns ```NoneType object has no attribute get()```...

Comment: "NoneType object has no attribute...": http://stackoverflow.com/q/1101750/7432 . This question has been asked dozens if not hundreds of times on stackoverflow.

Comment: DUH! I didn't know that. Maybe I should have looked for the NoneType error then. Thanks!